# in gawk, running under Windows -- how to output to a file

Tags: windows, export, output, gawk

This question is specific to gawk running on my Windows (64-bit) machine in which I have GNU tools in UNXUTILS that I invoke from the Command Prompt (don't have CygWin that many seem to).

Learnt awk Am used to having to check substituting double quotes for single quotes in AWK examples, etc, to make them work under my gawk. But no small tinkering would make the line, commented out below, work. Any guidance, suggestions to try, welcome. Thanks. Best, -Murgie

```
  END  { 
         for (key in order_qty) { print key, "O", order_qty[key]; }
         for (key in trade_qty) { print key, "T", trade_qty[key]; }
         for (key in dly_UE_qty) { print key, "UEQ", dly_UE_qty[key]; }
             #    for (key in dly_UE_qty) { { print key, "UEQ", dly_UE_qty[key]; } > 
             #        "..\Test_Output\just_Test_daily_Unexecuted_quantity.txt" }
             # note, above 2 commented lines are the one problem line
        print NR, "records processed."
        }
```

Have also just tried replacing "..\Test_Output\just_Test_daily_Unexecuted_quantity.txt" with just "just_Test_daily_Unexecuted_quantity.txt"  ... That doesn't work either. So the problem may not be just how the path is specified.

Also tried (i) double back-slashes instead of just one (ii) absolute path instead of relative path (iii) putting the "> output_file" outside the last "}" bracket instead of inside. Nothing works.

Googled "specifying path in GNU awk under Windows" and I only get links with how to set path when installing to make GNU tools work. Nothing related to specifying the full path for exporting output from within awk.

Most other things that I use within GNU (various filters, pipes) and 99% of the awk examples work just fine. Unable to pipe to a shell though nominally this GNU for Windows package does come sh and zsh. Best, -Murgie

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the environment that you are using to confirm this I think all that is missing is a line-continuation character. Try

```
END  { 
     for (key in order_qty) { print key, "O", order_qty[key]; }
     for (key in trade_qty) { print key, "T", trade_qty[key]; }
     for (key in dly_UE_qty) { print key, "UEQ", dly_UE_qty[key]; }
     for (key in dly_UE_qty) { { print key, "UEQ", dly_UE_qty[key]; } >\ 
         "..\Test_Output\just_Test_daily_Unexecuted_quantity.txt" }
     # ------ make sure \ is last char on the line, no spaces, tab! -^^^X
    print NR, "records processed."
    }
```

IHTH

Comment: @shelter It's not the continuation line. The actual line is whole. Also tried breaking up with the continuation slash as you showed. No luck. Thanks for trying. -Murgie

Comment: Ok, so does using Unix-sytle pathing to your output solve the problem? i.e. `"../Test_Ouptut/just....txt"`? .Or in the `for` loop that doesn't work, what happens if you take out the redirection to a file, is there output? If NO, then (and I've done this myself many times), make sure that there isn't a typo in your assignment to `dly_UE_qty`. Good luck.

Comment: Without this I do get output. At shell level I've run this code as >cat inputfiles | gawk -f script.awk > output.txt Was trying to save my coauthor some time in SAS by extracting just this separately. Knowing how to do this would be handy for several things. Learnt awk when I had access to SUN Sparc/UNIX. Now have only GNU via UNXUTILS under windows. Suspect it's the PATH specification that needs some tweaking. So far no luck. Best, -Murgie

Comment: well rather than use a relative path, test with the most basic path  you can (i.e.) where you have permissions to write a file to, And try both methods of `/path/2/file` VS `c:\path\to\file`. `gawk -f script.awk file >outfile` is the simplest usage. no need for `cat`, but not relevant you your current problem. It will really help if you modify your question above to include all your current state info, others may be able to spot the problem immediately. Good luck.